# why no native compiler of C# or other “productive” language?

Tags: c#, language-design

I've been reading about D and Go and how they aim at being compiled to machine code yet be convenient (like garbage collection, no need to manipulate pointers unless needed) and I agree that there is a need for such a language. However designers of both Go and D for some reason decided to invent a new language. Why? Why not take existing language which is popular, proven to be productive but is not compiled to native code like C#? What are technological reasons for that? Would it be hard to implement garbage collection (D does), linq or something entirely else?

Comment: GC implementation in native code needs pause the world or decimate throughput, this means they are not suited for real-time applications

Comment: eh? there's no magic to running in a VM that means GC suddenly works differently (ultimately) in native code. .NET (and java etc) are not suited for real-time applications anyway.

Comment: There was a Java to machine language compiler and then people stopped supporting it.

Comment: The point of D is to make C++ templates better. None of the managed languages (besides Lisp, of course) does it right. The point of Go is in concurrency - again, none of the managed languages (besides Erlang) does it the right way.

Comment: Note that while there may not be a "C# to native code compiler" of the form you're accustomed to, there *is* the [Ngen.exe (Native Image Generator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tool, which creates native images from CLR assemblies.

Comment: @ratchetfreak, your understanding of GC is severely distorted. Please stop spreading lies. Pause the world is not required, and it has nothing to do with native vs. interpreted.

Comment: "**designers of both Go and D for some reason decided to invent a new language. Why?**"  Questions which ask us to read the minds of other people are not answerable questions. If you have questions about the motivations of those people, **ask them**.

Comment: As a matter of fact, there is now a project that does this: [.NET Native](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dotnetnative.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of Java, its because they wanted it to run on many different architectures (remembers its roots were for an embedded system). Becuase of this they thought it would be better to provide an intermediate layer (the VM) so the java code could be written for the layer, so you wouldn't need to provide different implementations for each platform. Instead the layer would be constructed for each platform.

When Microsoft started to make .NET, its was so heavily designed to be Java (in fact it used much of the old J++ code they already had, and the chief designer was the guy who worked on their Java implementation) so its understandable they kept it as little changed as possible in order to produce something quicker. I think they also assumed that they could do more optimisations in the JIT at runtime so it wouldn't be so much slower.

Why they don't have a native compiler for it now is debatable. Probably they decided its not necessary, .NET code simply has the VM installed along with the runtime library so making it generate "pure" native code would be a waste of time for them.

Compare this to Mono that does generate native code however.

I think the guys who made D and Go didn't want to restrict themselves to using Microsoft technology (understandable), and possibly just because they like to create new language (there's enough languages about already, 2 new ones hardly matter!!).

Comment: Mono does not compile c# to native code.

Comment: @rossipedia, you're totally wrong. Mono can compile C# (via bytecode) to standalone native code (see MonoTouch).

Comment: @rossipedia - you're ignorant of the facts that [Mono does have AOT compilation](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT). Not sure why you got upvoted for that, do people think JIT-only is a good thing?

Comment: By that logic then so can .NET, via ngen

Comment: I'm fully aware that both mono and .NET _can_ generate native images, but these are generated from IL, not directly from c#

Comment: I'd argue that JIT can be superior to AOT, as the JIT compiler can use runtime statistics and heuristics to perform optimizations that would be impossible for the AOT compiler to make

Comment: @rossipedia, and do you know how many intermediate language stages are there in `gcc`? Evidently not...

Comment: @rossipedia sorry, .NET doesn't do native code even using ngen - that just does a pre-JIT so startup is faster. it bbasically preloads the assembly cache. It still uses the CLR and will throw away the cache and fall back to the IL if any dependencies change. What the mono AOT does is a true to-native code, like a C compiler creates. JIT is never better than AOT as although it could create better code, it can only do the quickest of optimisations to create that - no-one wants to wait 5 minutes for the JIT compiler to run after all, unlike an AOT compiler that can do this.

Comment: as for JIT heuristics... I *think* these are barely used as a) they're hard to determine what you need to do, b) the cost of collecting them will make your program run slower, and even then - would they produce enough meaningful optimisations that would make a noticeable difference. Only the simplest heuristics are used, I think. And besides, a good optimiser will produce better code from static code analysis anyway (it has the time to do this after all)

Comment: @sk-logic yes I do, no need to be rude about it. I will admit that I may have had a misunderstanding of how ngen works. Does mono offer C# direct to native compilation? I was under the impression that it did not, or if it did, it was only for specific architectures.

Comment: @rossipedia, why are you so obsessed about compilation being "direct"? Does it matter at all how many stages are there in between source code and native binary? No modern compiler is "direct". And, as for Mono, I'm talking about its ability to produce standalone binaries, working without the Mono runtime at all, as in MonoTouch. It's much more than `ngen` or a plain old `mono --aot`.

Comment: I'm not obsessed. I asked a question in response to a previous comment, apologies if I've offended you.

Comment: @rossipedia, mind explaining, how this question is relevant at all? Why does it matter if compilation is "direct" or not quite "direct", if, at the end of the chain, there is a native code running with no interpreter present at all?

Comment: This is has gone a bit off topic. I will be happy to discuss it with you in chat after the holidays if you wish.

Comment: @rossipedia, of course. In the meantime, mind removing your incorrect and misleading statement about mono not being able to compile to native?

Comment: @rossipedia I did provide you with a link :) It is restricted to certain platforms - ARM, x86 and x86_64. They says it also generates potentially better code due to being able to use more thorough optimisations.

Comment: @SK-logic no, because I believe that the evolution/context of a discussion about a question/answer can be just as informative as the answer itself, and unfortunately I cannot edit it anymore.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: Who is waiting 5 minutes for a JIT?

Comment: @RobertHarvey someone who has a JIT compiler that performs all the optimisations an offline compiler does. Which is nobody, as no JIT compilers perform those heavy optimisations.

Answer (score 6):

In all the usual implementations of C# and Java, at least part of the code *is* eventually compiled to native code.

The most widely used Java implementations are Oracle JDK / OpenJDK, which consist of an ahead-of-time compiler which compiles Java to JVM byte code and a mixed-mode VM, which starts interpreting the JVM byte code and JIT-compiles the performance-sensitive parts to native machine code.

In .NET, no code is ever interpreted, all code is compiled to native machine code before it is executed.

Answer (score 3):

You assume that the thought process behind Go and D was "we want a language compiled to native code that isn't C or C++". Then you wonder why the designers didn't just write native code compilers for Java or C#.

But who says that this was the thought process behind those languages? I can't speak for the designers, of course, but from what I've read, the primary idea behind D was "C++ has a syntax that makes compilers complicated and slow, and metaprogramming using templates is an unreadable nightmare; I can make a language that can do metaprogramming better than C++". Keep in mind that the primary designer of D is a C++ compiler writer.

Also, it's not that easy to just compile Java and C# to native code. Java's bytecode is part of the documented interface of the Java runtime environment. It's totally legal for a Java program to generate bytecode at runtime, and then use a class loader to load that. The same applies to C#. In fact, regular expression libraries and other things often do exactly that. You have mocking libraries, aspect libraries, all these things love to mess with bytecode. If you try to create a native-only environment for Java or C#, these things stop working. So at best you could compile a subset of Java to native code. But then you face the fact that all this stuff that's being done at runtime is actually an important part of the way these languages are used; it replaces things that are done with offline code generation or compile time tricks in other languages.

Comment: "It's totally legal for a Java program to generate bytecode at runtime, and then use a class loader to load that." -- yes, but once you have a bytecode to native code compiler, you can use that to implement a classloader that does that for native code at runtime.

Comment: Correct, you can do that, and I believe some existing Java-to-native implementations do it. But then you have to ship that compiler as part of the runtime. Part of the attraction of native code environments is that they're leaner than the big VMs; adding a bytecode compiler runs counter to that goal.

Answer (score 2):

Templates in C++ make it possible for a relatively small source file to generate an arbitrary number of different functions, each containing a different sequence of instructions, but in order for a program to actually run, the number of such functions must be bounded.

Generics in .NET languages like C# also allow a small source file to specify a huge number of functions, but there is no need to actually generate the instructions for any of them until such time as they're actually executed. Whereas C++ will choke if a template would generate an infinite number of functions, C# will have no problem, *given the ability to defer machine code generation until runtime*.

While it would be possible to have a compiler generate native code that included within itself a mechanism for generating additional code on demand, a code generator that produces optimized code is going to be a rather complicated beast.  It's easier to have the compiler render code into a form where generics do not have to be expanded out into machine instructions, and then have a JITter ("Just In Time compiler") which can take code of that form, along with a list of required type substitutions, and produce a machine-code representation of a method that works with the necessary types.

Comment: templating in C++ will generate only the functions that are actually used (and infinite number is wrong - you're limited to the number of types in the language/your code, so you'd have to create an infinite number of them to cause this problem....)  C# could generate the same code as C++ before runtime if it wished. Incidentally C# [creates generics the same way C++ creates them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342345/how-do-generics-get-compiled-by-the-jit-compiler), only it does it at runtime rather than compile time. So theoretically, C# could barf on an infinite number of functions too

Comment: @gbjbaanb: In C#, a method `Foo<T>(int n)` can legally call methods `Foo<X<T>>` and `Foo<Y<T>>`, which may in turn call `Foo<X<X<T>>`, `Foo<X<Y<T>>`, `Foo<Y<X<T>>`, and `Foo<Y<Y<T>>`, etc.  I think C++ would choke on such a construct, but C# allows it.  The code for `Foo<X<Y<T>>` won't be generated unless or until it's actually called; calling it will generate types `Foo<X<X<Y<T>>>` and `Foo<Y<X<Y<T>>>`, but those types' methods (and the types they need) won't be generated unless or until they are called.

Comment: C++ happily does such things - check out the stl for examples of deeply nested container types. Even in these cases, the code is still only generated when referenced.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: What if the generated types depend upon user input?  For example, if `String Foo<T>(int n) where T:new` calls `(new T).ToString()` if `n` is one or less, `Foo<X<T>>(n>>1)` if n is odd, or `Foo<Y<T>>(n>>1)` if n is even?  `Foo<int>` will generate a different type for every positive value of n.  How would C++ know which values of `n` `Foo<int>` might be called with?

Comment: are you saying that C# will happily generate code for an infinite recursion of types based on a parameter. I believe C++ will refuse to compile a self-referential template. C# should not either as you would easily end up in a neverending code-generating loop (not to mention the WTF-ness of such code)

Comment: @gbjbaanb: I would expect C++ compilation to simply fail; C# compilation, however, will not only succeed, but yield a program that runs just fine.  It will be necessary to have conditions at run-time which prevent an endless type explosion, but the same applies with ordinary recursion which is--within reason--considered a perfectly acceptable programming paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Jorg's remark -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.90).aspx

If one looks at the rather vast collection of variations in CPU architectures that .NET runs on, one can see some value in converting to machine code at the last possible instant.  Looking at the permutations of Pentiums, Atoms, Xeons, Opterons, etc. one finds various instruction subsets present or absent, variations in front side busses, graphics co-processors, etc. Is it a good idea for developers writing CRUD to spend even a second thinking about this stuff?

Comment: You mean x86 and x86_64 :-) Mono says *"In some operating system configurations (mostly embedded systems) the operating system services for generating code dynamically are not available, this prevents Mono's JIT from working."* - you're basically right though, but I think you still need to understand what services you get, your image processing code may run appallingly slowly if you expect SSE instructions to be present and they're not - so you have to worry about anyway. C devs don't have a problem doing this so its not a huge issue.